# Describe this feature of a programming language

Tags: python, arrays, return-value

Is there a way to describe the feature of a programming language that allows you to do something like the following:

```
$foo = return_an_array()[0];
```

I love this feature in python, and I hate that it's missing in PHP. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Which feature? assignment, function call, or indexing?

Comment: How about *ordinary-language-features-missing-in-php*?

Comment: I couldn't add that as a tag, because it exceeds the 25 character maximum :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: chaining? like obj.method1().method2()?

Comment: @Greg - Now, see, if that was an answer, you'd be the best answer.

Comment: It's not possible in PHP? Really? If so, it's yet another reason I'm glad to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

Array indexing on arbitrary expressions